# Subquery inside of Group By?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example that's working, but not getting everything I need:

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(price) AS total_revenue 
FROM payments 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

That's getting the total revenue (adding `price`), but I also need to get the total price where `vendor = '22' AND credited = 'Vendor'` (like I did with price, on a per day basis).

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(price) AS total_revenue, 
       (SELECT SUM(price) WHERE vendor = '22' AND credited = 'Vendor') AS vendor_revenue 
FROM payments 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

What am I doing wrong or is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is the best way to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) AS ts,
    SUM(price) AS total_revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vendor = '22' AND credited = 'Vendor' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS vendor_revenue
FROM payments
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original query is malformed -- you have `select *` with `group by`.

```
SELECT DATE(p.timestamp), SUM(price) AS total_revenue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vendor = 22 AND credited = 'Vendor' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as vendor_22_price
FROM payments p
GROUP BY DATE(p.timestamp)
```